# Path to JAVA not found?

Tags: java, r, web-scraping, rvest, rselenium

```
rD <- rsDriver(browser="chrome", chromever = '89.0.4389.90')
Error in java_check() : 
  PATH to JAVA not found. Please check JAVA is installed.
```

What I have above is the error I get but I DO have java installed. I'm essentially using someone's code that is found here: https://github.com/djblechn-su/nba-player-team-ids/blob/master/NBAScrape.R
to do the exact same thing that they did but with the updated roster.

I have put in MY version of chrome, though.
I'm not sure what else to do.

Comment: Check your system `PATH`, it is likely that it isn't by default added. Find where your `java.exe` (or whatever system you have) is installed, then add that path to your system `PATH`. If you want to do it in R alone, you can use `Sys.getenv("PATH")` to see what R "sees" of it, and then `Sys.setenv(PATH=...)` to update it.

Comment: @r2evans I have :  Sys.setenv(PATH="C:\Users\ap3340\Documents\MATLAB\sys\java\jre\win64\jre\bin")I have attempted to run this in the console but get a:

Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting ""C:\U"

Comment: The backslash \ is an escape character, either use \\ or use / for example `C:\\Users\\ap3340\\...` or `C:/Users/ap3340/...`

Comment: Also, the `PATH` should have many directories in it, not just one. By setting it to just one, you won't find all of the other utilities and command you will likely need to do other things.

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67994285/using-rselenium-for-web-scraping-across-windows-and-mac/68034354#68034354